# tkinter : how "naviguate" between windows

Tags: tkinter

i'm learning.
i have a root window, in which a player clicks a button to launch, then selects a game to play (1 , 2 or...) by clicking another button.

this opens a new generic window with some parameters that i pass through depending on the game selected. (my_window in the code below)

in this new window,I can't find a way to make sure that printing labels, or actually lauching the game is done in my_window ??

in the code below , i'm simulating it with the the label(   Label(my_window, text = "game_num value"  + str(game_num)).grid( row =5, column = 0 ) in the function Launch_the_game.
this label is printed in root and not in my_window
how come ?

am i not calling the windows right ? or creating them right ?
thank you

```
from tkinter import *

def launch_the_game():
        global my_window
        global game_num

        Label(my_window, text = "game_num value"  + str(game_num)).pack()
        
def open_new_window(game_num,game_name, dimensions, game_rule):
    global my_window

    my_window = Toplevel()
    my_window.title(game_name)
    my_window.geometry(dimensions)
    Label(my_window, text = "" + game_rule).grid( row = 3, column = 0)
    Button(my_window, text = "LAUNCH " + game_name, command= launch_the_game ) .grid( row = 4, column = 0) 


def assign_game(value):

    global game_name
    global dimensions
    global game_rule
    global game_num
    global my_window
    
    game_num = value

    if value  == 1:
        game_name  = "Guess my number"
        dimensions = "400x600"
        game_rule = " guess a number between 0 and 100"
        game_num = str(value)

    my_window=open_new_window(game_num,game_name, dimensions, game_rule)

    
def my_click_name_UI():

    btn1 = Button(root, text="Guess my number", command= lambda *args: assign_game(1)).pack()
    btn2 = Button(root, text="Guess my name", command= lambda *args: assign_game(2)).pack()

        
root = Tk(className =' Best game ever ! ')
root.geometry("450x150")
root.configure(bg="light blue")
btn3 = Button(root, text="Go play the games!", command=my_click_name_UI)
btn3.pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

my friend found the problem.
i'mm assigning my_window = open_new_window.... which returns "blank" and blank is probably = root.
so 2 ways of fixing.
one would be  to

```
        game_name  = "Guess my number"
        dimensions = "400x600"
        game_rule = " guess a number between 0 and 100"
        game_num = str(value)

  open_new_window(game_num,game_name, dimensions, game_rule)
```

Or

```
    global my_window

    my_window = Toplevel()
    my_window.title(game_name)
    my_window.geometry(dimensions)
    Label(my_window, text = "" + game_rule).grid( row = 3, column = 0)
    Button(my_window, text = "LAUNCH " + game_name, command= launch_the_game ) .grid( row = 4, column = 0) 
    return my_window
```

in both cases this works .
He also told me to start learning what classes are , and to write my code properly, for ease of reading ;)

keep on learning !